# Changing CHMOD in wamp

Tags: wamp, chmod

I want to change the chmod in wamp but I don't know how.

> Set the CHMOD to 777 or 775 (depending on the server configuration) to
>   the folder 'photos'.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't know what to do? Did you try `man chmod`? Did you try just googling and doing some research into your Q first? I understand that you're new so please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @xlm Yes I tried Google but it didn't work. I don't know how to change CHMOD in wampserver that I installed on my computer if possible. I'm using windows 7. I want to know the whole process. I don't know what is "man chmod" and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: As you are on a windows machine there is no `chmod` it's a UNIX/LINUX command. If you are following a tutorial, you dont need to do this step on a windows machine.